# Struggling with 'crawling' several webpages for one specific term

Tags: python, web, web-crawler, html

I have made a program in python that asks for a search term and webpage to be searched. I thought it would be good to add functionality where it could 'crawl' many webpages. I did this by creating a class, as it is the only way that I know of where you can inherit from something. Here my problem arises. The class function gets called correctly if i put it in. However for what I need it to do I do not know where to place the call for the class function as i need things that can only get from certain functions but that aren't available in other functions.

```
import urllib.request
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class trawler(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def handle_starttag(self,webpage,term):
        for tag in webpage:
            if tag == 'a':
                if attrs == 'href':
                    for value in attrs:
                        search_Webpage_2(term, value)

trawl = trawler()

def main():
    print('Please enter your search term:')
    searchTerm = input('> ')

    print('Please enter the WebSite to be searched:')
    searchWebsite = input('> ')

    search_Webpage(searchTerm, searchWebsite)

def open_Webpage(url):
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    webPage = response.read()
    return webPage.decode()

def open_Webpage_2(url):
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    webPage = response.read()
    return webPage.decode()

def search_Webpage(term, url):
    if term in open_Webpage(url):
        print ('Word:',term,'was found in WebPage:',url)
    else:
        print ('No matches in WebSite:',url)

def search_Webpage_2(term, url):
    if term in open_Webpage_2(url):
        print ('Word:',term,'was found in WebPage:',url)
    else:
        print ('No matches in WebSite:',url)
main()
```

trawl.handle_starttag takes webpage, which is the raw html of the webpage and the search term.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is there a reason that there are two copies of each function? These are distracting from the solution and I'd recommend deleting them if not used.

Comment: They are used for the class function. I added them to ensure the the program would run correctly

Comment: OK, I see now. In general, a good principle to follow is DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself. So if you ever have to write two functions or code segments that are identical, that's a sure sign you need to refactor. My advice would be to separate out the functions that 1) search the page for keywords, 2) extract the links from the page and then 3) queue those extra links for searching. That's quite a lot of changes though so might not be suitable as an answer.